# ¿Cómo hacer un menú a dos renglones, centrado en WordPress?

Tags: wordpress

Lo hice en HTML, pero quiero migrar a WordPress y que quede de esta misma manera:

HTML:

```
<nav id="botonera" class="col-lg-9 col-md-9 col-sm-12 col-xs-12 collapse navbar-collapse pull-right">

        <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
            <li><a href="servicios.php"><b>Servicios</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="localizatusucursal.php"><b>Localiza tu Sucursal</b></a></li>
            <li data_temp_dwid="1"><a href="consultaderesultados.php" data_temp_dwid="2"><strong data_temp_dwid="3">Consulta de Resultados</strong></a></li>
            <li><a href="facturacionelectronica.php"><b>Facturación Electrónica</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="medicos.php"><b>Médicos</b></a></li>
            <li><a href="contacto.php"><b>Contacto</b></a></li>
        </ul>

    </nav>
```

En WordPress tengo este código para el menú:

```
<div class="main-header-bar-wrap">
<div class="main-header-bar">
    <?php astra_main_header_bar_top(); ?>
    <div class="ast-container">

        <div class="ast-flex main-header-container">
            <?php astra_masthead_content(); ?>
        </div><!-- Main Header Container -->
    </div><!-- ast-row -->
    <?php astra_main_header_bar_bottom(); ?>
</div> <!-- Main Header Bar -->
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No es en **header-main-layout.php** donde tienes que tocar, sino que la clave está en las lineas 669-673 del fichero **extras.php** que está en la carpeta **/inc** del theme Astra:

```
            669      $items_wrap  = '<nav itemtype="https://schema.org/SiteNavigationElement" itemscope="itemscope" id="site-navigation" class="ast-flex-grow-1" role="navigation" aria-label="' . esc_attr( 'Site Navigation', 'astra' ) . '">';
            670      $items_wrap .= '<div class="main-navigation">';
            671      $items_wrap .= '<ul id="%1$s" class="%2$s">%3$s</ul>';
            672      $items_wrap .= '</div>';
            673      $items_wrap .= '</nav>';
```

Inserta tu código en lugar del parámetro **%3$s** de la línea 671

Comment: ¿Agrego solo los ´data_temp_dwid´ o todo el menú?

Comment: Saca copia de seguridad de extras.php, renombrando la copia a _extras.php.

Cambia el parámetro %3$s por el código de los elementos <li> de tu menú.

Añade las clases que quieres utilizar:
1) en la línea 669 en el elemento <nav> tienes que incluir el id y las clases que tu utilizas en tu código HTML para el nav.

2) en la línea 671 en el elemento <ul> tienes que agregar la clase "nav navbar-nav" al código existente. Quedaría:
class="%2$s nav navbar-nav"

3) También estudia la posibilidad de borrar las líneas 670 y 672, ya que te agregan un div que no sé si lo necesitas.

Comment: Pensándolo mejor, te van a fallar los enlaces... Para evitarlo, no copies los li en lugar del parámetro %3$s, sino simplemente agrega las clases y los id necesarios en los elementos <nav> y <ul> de las líneas 669 y 671, pero deja el parámetro %3$s.
Luego ve a la administración de wordpress e incluye los enlaces de tus páginas en WP ya que si no, te van a fallar los enlaces puesto que tu menu apunta a páginas estáticas.